# Restoring SPSite not working with different versions

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-foundation

I'm having issues with restoring my .bak files to my own sharepoint environment due to version difference.

My version is currently: 
**Sharepoint Server with Enterprise Client Access License**
**Ms sharepoint Foundation 2010 core :** 14.0.4763.1000 
**Security Update of Ms sharepoint Foundation 2010**(kb2494001) 14.0.6106.5008

Server Version(Where I'm creating my Backups): 
**SharePoint Server with Enterprise Client Access License** 
**Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 Core :** 14.0.4763.1000 
**Security Update for Office SharePoint Foundation 2010** (KB2345322) : 14.0.5123.5002

I would like to know if there is a way I could enable my backups from the Server to be compatible with my version. My only option is to downgrade my version since I'm not an admin to the server.

Does my Client Access License an issue? Can I just downgrade my security update to match the one in the server? If there is would you please be kind enough to tell me how. ?

Here is the error message:

*Restore-SPSite : Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft SharePoin
t Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the current version. Th
e backup file should be restored to a server with version '14.0.0.5123' or late
r.
At line:1 char:15
+ Restore-SPSite <<<<  "http://quiel-pc/sites/CMAPSQL" -Path "c:\CMAP.bak" -For
ce
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:
   SPCmdletRestoreSite) [Restore-SPSite], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreS
   ite*

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?  Typically you can restore a site to a version number HIGHER than the source farm, but not lower.

Comment: I updated the question with the error message. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: You cannot downgrade once you installed the patch

Comment: If i would be updating the server with the site collections in it. would there be any problems?

Answer (score 1):

The updates on your target/destination server are not properly applied so it has a different build number, prior to the Aug 2010 CU on the source system where the update is applied.

Make sure that you apply both the Foundation and the Server patch and then complete the upgrade by running psconfig or the configuration wizard.

Comment: Would there be any issues with the existing siteCollections that were made from tha lower version?

Comment: You can go lower version (patch) to a later version (patch).  The message you are seeing tells me that the version you are providing us for the destination is not correct or not correctly installed.

Comment: the backup file is from a lower version. If that was the case how could i make it work? would you be kind to show me how?

Comment: @Mark - you would have to provision a farm somewhere with an older version, then do the upgrades to get it to the right version.  You can also use content DBs to migrate data from one env. to another, and attaching a content DB will automatically upgrade to teh farm ver if required.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the server where you are creating the back up is not upgraded to SP1 but the server where you are trying to restore is upgraded to SP1.

So may be what you can do is first upgrade the server(where you are creating the backup) with SP1 and then take the backup and restore.

Comment: Sad part is that Upgrading the Server is not option since i don't have priviledges :( the one im restoring to is just in my laptop. I installed it for my development purposes. Could i just downgrade my version?